# How to check which parameters of case class have default value using scala reflection 2.10

Tags: scala, reflection, macros

My task is to find names of parameters of case class, for which there are default values.

In 2.9 I was using ScalaSigParser from scalap and did something similar to:

```
(...)
case x: MethodSymbol if x.name.startsWith("init$default$") => (...)
(...)
```

I was hoping that reflection in 2.10 would give me easier access to this kind of information.

Eventually I'd like to write a macro, which I would include in case class' companion object, which would automatically create a code for serialization/deserialization of that case class. To do that I need to know which parameters have default values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no way to do that, however I've just submitted a pull request (https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/1047) that adds `TermSymbol.isDefaultParam`, which exposes the requested functionality. I hope it will make it into RC1 and 2.10.0-final.

```
scala> case class C(x: Int, y: Int = 2)
defined class C

scala> val ctor = typeOf[C].declaration(nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
ctor @ 39fe9830: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = constructor C

scala> ctor.params.flatten filter (_.asTerm.isDefaultParam)
res0 @ 7ad2093b: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = List(value y)
```

Comment: Allrighty the pull request has been merged, and it will be included in 2.10.0.

Comment: It appears that `params` is now `paramss` and the `isDefaultParam` method is renamed to `isParamWithDefault` in both scala 2.10 and 2.11